# How install office 2010 under Wine in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, microsoft-office, wine

How do I install office 2010 under Wine in Ubuntu Linux? What is the difference between the installation of office 2007 and office 2010 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) (free). Its a GUI for install a lot of WINE apps. It works with Office 2007/2010, no joke. Makes me like Ubuntu a whole lot more!

Comment: It uses Wine. Only downloads the neccessary fixes-configs. Well.. it makes things work.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that playonlinux [doesn't create file associations or menu entries](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-8860.html). For me that renders it unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at:
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336

It shows that it's actual un-doable, You will not be able to install office 2010 in Ubuntu, OpenOffice or LibreOffice are the only ones.

Comment: Though they lack Outlook...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336

> Current Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick" x86_64 (+ variants like Kubuntu) - Dec 29 2010 - 1.3.10
>
> Installs: Yes, Runs: Yes, Rating: Bronze
>
> What works: Installation when installer
>   doesn't download files from the
>   internet (office 2010 trial
>   professional, box version)
>
> What does not: Installation when
>   installer download files from the
>   internet (office 2010 trial home &
>   student, home & Business)
>
> What was not tested: Activation online
>
> Additional Comments
>
> I tested Office 2010 Trial Professional, previously I tested Office 2010 trial Home and Student

Office 2010 Home and Student wouldn't install or run for the same bug submitter.

Keep in mind that this report was submitted as such:

> This entry is just for testing *the installer* of Microsoft Office 2010 (aka Office 14) office suite.
>
> Reports on specific programs included in Office 2010 should be submitted to their respective AppDB entries.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with wine.

You would need to run Office 2010 on top of [crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover/).  Not free.

Comment: Apparently not really possible in Crossover either: http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=7437 "These sort of applications either do not install and/or run, for any of a number of reasons. We suggest you don't even try to use them on the current version of CrossOver."

Comment: @techie007, hmm you're right.  Office 2000 was gold and things seem to have worsened with newer versions.

Comment: Yeah, I think it has to do with neer Office versions depending way more MSXML and .NET than previously.

Comment: @techie007: The link you provided was for [Office 2010](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=7437) which has bronze level support, but [Office 2010 SP1](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=10258) has silver level support.

Answer (score 1):

The Office 2010 32 bit installer has Platinum status http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336 so should install without a hitch although you might find Playonlinux helpful. The test only seems to cover Word, Excel and Powerpoint and there are individual entries for each of the applications. I have managed to do this on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit and it seems fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Office 10 and Adobe Photoshop CS 5 through Wine. There is a tutorial that shows [how to install Office 10 and other softwares in Wine](http://glug.nith.ac.in/tutorials.php).